# Xamarin forms listview no working using MVVM. please do i do this on to a viewmodel?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

Below is the xaml for listview and i am binding it to a viewmodel class. on start-up, this code is suppose to trigger nd display all the list of declined request. rather, it is not doing so.
Please can anyone help?

```
enter code here
<ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding DeclinedRequest, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Label Text="FirstName" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                        <Label Text="Phone Contect" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        <Button Grid.Row="2" Text="Remove" BorderColor="IndianRed"  BorderWidth="4" 
                            BorderRadius="20" 
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            FontSize="Large" TextColor="Black" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" 
                                                                      BackgroundColor="White"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
enter code here
```

See the viewModel below where-in when the code is executed, it is suppose to
get the retrieved items from my db....

```
     public List<DryCleanerCustomerMapModel> ServiceRequest { get => 
         IncomingRequest(); }
        private List<DryCleanerCustomerMapModel> IncomingRequest()
        {
            int requestStatus = (int)RequestStatusEnum.pendingRequest;
            var serviceRequest =       
_dryCleanerCustomerMapAppService.GetMapByEmail(Session.GetSessionValue(), requestStatus);
            if (serviceRequest.Any())
            {
                RequestTitle = "You have a new request";
                return serviceRequest;
            }
            else
            {
                RequestTitle = "You have no request";
                return null;
            }
        }

        private string requestTitle;
        public string RequestTitle
        {
            get => requestTitle;
            set
            {
                requestTitle = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
                PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(RequestTitle)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to delete hthe classes responsible for these, created another one, still didn't work. Any idea what I'd have to do?

Comment: Where is the code of the viewmodel and the startup part with the binding?

Comment: Just added it @SirRufo. see viewmodel code above..

Comment: Oh, that is easy: You bind to the wrong property. ListView => DeclinedRequest, ViewModel => ServiceRequest

Comment: changed that, still didn't.. here is it. i used a breakpoint on the viewmodel. My breakpoint didn't hit. the app just stayed idle. literally nothing happened

Comment: Did you debug the startup code where you ind the viewmodel to the view (code part you did not show us)? We cannot help without all relevant code parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please make sure your `ItemsSource="{Binding DeclinedRequest, Mode=TwoWay}"` in the `Listview` binding `DeclinedRequest` , you ViewModel should be `DeclinedRequest` as well, Then you used `ListView` and add the `ViewCell` in `DataTemplate` tab like following code.

```
  <ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding DeclinedRequest, Mode=TwoWay}" RowHeight="150">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>


                            <Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Label Text="FirstName" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                        <Label Text="Phone Contect" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        <Button Grid.Row="2" Text="Remove" BorderColor="IndianRed"  BorderWidth="4" 
                            BorderRadius="20" 
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            FontSize="Large" TextColor="Black" Command="{Binding BindingContext.RemoveCommand}" 
                                                                      BackgroundColor="White"/>
                    </Grid>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

In the this layout background, you should add `BindingContext = new MyViewModel();`

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
        }
```

I used static data to make a test. Here is code.

```
   public class MyViewModel { 
        public ICommand RemoveCommand { protected set; get; }

        public ObservableCollection<DryCleanerCustomerMapModel> DeclinedRequest
        {
            get =>IncomingRequest();
        }
        private ObservableCollection<DryCleanerCustomerMapModel> IncomingRequest()
        {
            var mylist=new ObservableCollection<DryCleanerCustomerMapModel>();
            mylist.Add(new DryCleanerCustomerMapModel() { FirstName="test1", PhoneNumber=123456789 });
            mylist.Add(new DryCleanerCustomerMapModel() { FirstName = "test2", PhoneNumber = 123456789 });
            mylist.Add(new DryCleanerCustomerMapModel() { FirstName = "test3", PhoneNumber = 123456789 });
            mylist.Add(new DryCleanerCustomerMapModel() { FirstName = "test4", PhoneNumber = 123456789 });
            return mylist;
        }
            public MyViewModel()
        {
            RemoveCommand= new Command<DryCleanerCustomerMapModel>((key) =>
            {

                DeclinedRequest.Remove(key);


            });

        }

        //public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        //protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        //{
        //    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        //}
    }
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]

If you want to achieve the remove function for `Button`, you should change the `Buttom` xaml code like following format.

```
   <ListView x:Name="Mylist"
            ItemsSource="{Binding DeclinedRequest, Mode=TwoWay}" RowHeight="150">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>


                            <Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Label Text="FirstName" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                        <Label Text="Phone Contect" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        <Button Grid.Row="2" Text="Remove" BorderColor="IndianRed"  BorderWidth="4" 
                            BorderRadius="20" 
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            FontSize="Large" TextColor="Black" Command="{Binding BindingContext.RemoveCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=Mylist}}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                                      BackgroundColor="White"/>
                    </Grid>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

You should change the ViewModel like following code.

```
    public class MyViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged { 
        public ICommand RemoveCommand { protected set; get; }
         ObservableCollection<DryCleanerCustomerMapModel> mylist;
        public ObservableCollection<DryCleanerCustomerMapModel> DeclinedRequest
        {
            get => IncomingRequest();
            set
            {
                if (mylist != value)
                {
                    mylist = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("DeclinedRequest");

                }
            }
        }
        // public ObservableCollection<DryCleanerCustomerMapModel> DeclinedRequest { get; set; }
        private ObservableCollection<DryCleanerCustomerMapModel> IncomingRequest()
        {
            mylist = new ObservableCollection<DryCleanerCustomerMapModel>();
            mylist.Add(new DryCleanerCustomerMapModel() { FirstName = "test1", PhoneNumber = 123456789 });
            mylist.Add(new DryCleanerCustomerMapModel() { FirstName = "test2", PhoneNumber = 123456789 });
            mylist.Add(new DryCleanerCustomerMapModel() { FirstName = "test3", PhoneNumber = 123456789 });
            mylist.Add(new DryCleanerCustomerMapModel() { FirstName = "test4", PhoneNumber = 123456789 });
            return mylist;
        }
        public MyViewModel()
        {

            RemoveCommand = new Command<DryCleanerCustomerMapModel>( (key) =>
            {
                var my = (DryCleanerCustomerMapModel)key ;
                mylist.Remove(my);


            });

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Here is running gif.

[image]

Comment: Are there any update for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the left upper corner), it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: accepted. this worked Man. Thanks a whole lot. I am really grateful

Comment: @DanielIbangada Hi bro, please click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer, this operation mean accept this answer.

Comment: Hey guys, this is the correct answer.  Thanks once again @leon

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually binding to ServiceRequest collection it needs to be an `ObservableCollection` not a `List`